Main and side-premises in the context of normalization for natural deduction.
I am trying to understand the concept of main premises and side premises in the context of normalization/cut-elimination, and specifically in the example of $\lor$-elimination (usually shortened as $\lor E$).
Let's say we have as main premise $\varphi \lor \psi$. Let's also assume that we derive $[\varphi] \vdash \sigma$ and $[\psi] \vdash \sigma$ ($[]$ indicating assumption). I am not sure how to write prooftrees here; please comment if you know how.
What exactly is counted as the side-premise in this rule, is it:

$\sigma,\sigma$.
$[\varphi] \vdash \sigma, [\psi] \vdash \sigma$
?

Remark: This question might perhaps be somewhat elementary; I just want to make sure I understand the definition correctly.
If it is true that the terms are not conventional, than perhaps cf. with principal for main premise, and non-principal for side premise.

@SAAD Using an s instead of z is common in England English and direct variants. It is not a typo.

These terms are not standard AFAIK and depend on how your author/teacher defined them. You would have to tell us what they mean.

An acquaintance told me principal (for main premise) is the closest one, so he supposed non-principal would be side premise.
